# Why does this VC++ workaround not work in GCC or clang?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I came across [this interesting article](http://b.atch.se/posts/constexpr-counter/) about how to implement a compile time counter in C++.

The author provides [a workaround for Visual C++](http://b.atch.se/posts/constexpr-counter/#appendix-msvc-workaround). I slightly modified it and compiled it [online](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) and it indeed works when compiled with Visual C++.

```
#include <iostream>

template<int N>
struct flag {
  friend constexpr int adl_flag (flag<N>);
};

template<int N>
struct writer {
  friend constexpr int adl_flag (flag<N>) {
    return N;
  }

  static constexpr int value = N;
};

template<int N, class = char[noexcept(adl_flag(flag<N> ()))?+1:-1]>
int constexpr reader (int, flag<N>) {
  return N;
}

template<int N>
int constexpr reader (float, flag<N>, int R = reader (0, flag<N-1> ())) {
  return R;
}

int constexpr reader (float, flag<0>) {
  return 0;
}

template<int N = 1, int C = reader (0, flag<32> ())>
int constexpr next (int R = writer<C + N>::value) {
  return R;
}


int main () {
  constexpr int a = next();
  constexpr int b = next();
  constexpr int c = next();

  std::cout << a << " " << b  << " " << c << std::endl;
  static_assert (a == 1 && b == a+1 && c == b+1, "try again");
}
```

**output with VC++**

```
1 2 3
```

However, the assertation in that code fails for both [GCC](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/HUwwy2xn8zgn1MpS) and [clang](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/nzKYSUTskLh5azh5). When commenting out the assertion, the [output is](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/9zdRaAVbWzgSKy6j):

```
1 1 1
```

Is this workaround exploiting a bug in VC++ or should it work in GCC/clang as well?

Comment: Want to stick any relevant text into your question rather than external links?  The question will be useless when the links die...

Comment: Compile time counters are so directly on the edge of the language that it's difficult to say anything definitive, except don't rely on such features and techniques.

Comment: Perhaps you can annotate this code to help people like me to understand it without endlessly pondering over it.